# How to deploy a Laravel 5 using composer and FTP

Tags: laravel, deployment

I built a project using Laravel 5 on my dev machine and now I'd like to deploy it.
One solution that came to my mind is to upload everything using FTP but I guess there is a better way.

I uploaded the composer.json but I receive tons of errors.
I have ssh/root access but using GIT is not an option.

Comment: Make sure you can use composer binary on your server and you are set, upload everything except vendor folder set permissions and `$ composer install` (from composer.lock file).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working like a charm. You could add an answer so I can Up vote it. (PS: I was running composer update, not composer install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you can use composer binary on your server and you are set

- upload every file except vendor folder (you may use some [FTPS manager](https://www.google.com/#q=ftp%20manager%20gitignore) that reads git-ignore file and does not upload ignored files)
- set permissions to `./storage` folder (browse thru this [severfault thread](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years))
- make sure your web server root is `./public`
- create env file (that is not going to be changed ever, until you want) and do not overwrite it with "local" [env file](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration).
- `$ composer install` (installs everything from composer.lock)
- `$ composer update` (updates from repositories again, **do test** on local before updating on production)